# android P actions - app not receiving intent action in broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, actions-on-google

What i am doing is making an app that when user uses google assistant to say "turn on my app" then it asked "do you want to turn on my app" and then user replies "yes" or "yes please" and i want it to open my app.  I am expecting that a broadcastReciever will be called with the intent that the google assistant sent and i will know how to react. Lets see what i have done so far and i am testing this all on Android P emulator:

here is what the server side has on google:

[image]

[image]

[image]

then in the android manifest i have declared a broadcastreciever so that it can listen for the custom intent action i created above called *action_intent_OPEN_CALL_MUSIC*:

```
 <receiver android:name=".receivers.MyGoogleAssistantReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="action_intent_OPEN_CALL_MUSIC" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

when i then use the google assistant in the emulator no broadcast is received in the app, what am i doing wrong ?

```
public class MyGoogleAssistantReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("myTag","got an intent:" + intent.getAction()); //nothing hits here,why ?
}
```

}

do i have to add something in xml/actions.xml even though its all local ?

Comment: Is that Intent specifically targetting your Receiver?

Comment: How would I do that? I've already set the filter in the manifest. Anything else?

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing now. One minute.

Comment: I think you should read the docs for Android: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/engage/actions-on-google.

Comment: so is there no way for the android client to handle it ? it be go through "fulliment" by a back end server ? i